# Why does Pandas cut return unequal sized bins?

Tags: python, pandas

In the `Examples` section for [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), the following is mentioned:

`Discretize into three equal-sized bins.`

```
pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)

[(0.994, 3.0], (5.0, 7.0], (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], ...
Categories (3, interval[float64, right]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] ...
```

How are the bins equal sized? The first bin seems larger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> int : Defines the number of equal-width bins in the range of x. The
> range of x is extended by .1% on each side to include the minimum and
> maximum values of x.

So, it is extending the lower bin to capture the lowest value, 1.

Now watch if we close on the other size with `right=False`

```
pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3, right=False)
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 3.0), [5.0, 7.006), [5.0, 7.006), [3.0, 5.0), [5.0, 7.006), [3.0, 5.0)]
Categories (3, interval[float64, left]): [[1.0, 3.0) < [3.0, 5.0) < [5.0, 7.006)]
```

The top value is extended to capture 7.